# Need help to check a quote from Hecke's "Lectures on Dirichlet Series, Modular Functions and Quadratic Forms"

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

I'd like to check the accuracy of a reference to Hecke's 1938 "Lectures on Dirichlet Series, Modular Functions and Quadratic Forms" implicit in eq. 4.8 on p. 50 of J. G. Leo's dissertation, which is here:

http://halfaya.org/ucla/research/thesis.pdf

The Hecke theorem in question describes an analogue of the normalized weight 4 Eisenstein series for the full modular group that is itself modular with weight 4 under the transformations of the $m^{th}$ Hecke group $G(2\cos (\pi/m))$. (I'll typeset Leo's rather intricate eq.4.8 if necessary, but I'm hoping to avoid that, since people can find it with a few mouse-clicks.) Leo seems to say that his equation 4.8 is an immediate consequence of something in Hecke's book, but doesn't give page numbers, and the book is hard to find under the present no-libraries circumstances. I want to implement Leo's eq. 4.8 in a computer algebra system; right now my code is not generating plausible output. So, while I debug, I think it's sensible to rule out a typographical error or other mistake in Leo's quote. If someone with access to Hecke's book can reply with a yes or a no as to Leo's accuracy, it would help me, and if that person could provide me with the relevant page numbers in Hecke's book, it would help me even more, because I could then look for a copy of those few pages legally, under fair-use.Thank you.